# Textrunner algorithm: what is a dependency chain?

Tags: nlp

On page 3 of [Open information extraction from the web](http://turing.cs.washington.edu/papers/ijcai07.pdf) Banko et al describe a self-supervised classifier for relation extraction that that looks at a potential relations between noun phrases. They say that if a sequence of words linking two noun phrases does not meet certain criteria the relation is labeled as "negative." If the sequence of words does meet all criteria it is labeled as positive.

One of the criteria that they list is that:

> There exists a dependency chain between Ei and Ej that is no longer
>   than a certain length.

What are they talking about here? What is a dependency chain? How do you identify a dependency chain?

Comment: seems off-topic to me.

Comment: @GregS this is a question about a major algorithm about a major problem in natural language processing. There is not much written about it in an accessible way so SO could be a huge help for NLP programmers who want to do relation extraction.

Comment: did you read about dependency parsing?

Comment: @shyamupa I do not know what that is. Can you post links?

Comment: http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~nivre/docs/05133.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The "dependency chain", in this case, appears just to be the length/number of words between the two entities. (Bill and Bob)

"Bill" "saw" "Bob"
"Saw" is the chain with a length of 1

"Bill" "jumped in his car and drove away after eating" "lunch"
"jumped in his car and drove away after eating" is well long(9) and not a good relation.

"Bob" "is married to" "Bill" 
"is married to" is the type of relation that the program is looking for. Remember it is trying to do this all **automatically**. Then with good combinations of relations try to figure out new knowledge.

IF x "is-married-to" y AND z "is-the-son-of" x THEN z "is-the-son-of" y